# How can I order a ggplot heatmap based on the value of a column?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

The following R snippet

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data <- data.frame(
          item  = c('foo', 'bar', 'baz'),
          val_1 = c(   7 ,    9 ,    3 ),
          val_2 = c(   1 ,    2 ,    3 )
        );

data

data$tot = data$val_1 + data$val_2;

data.molten = melt(data);

ggplot(
   data = data.molten,
   aes(x = variable, y = item ))  +
   geom_tile(aes(fill  = value))  +
   geom_text(aes(label = value))
```

produces

[image]

Is there a possibility to have it ordered by the value of `tot` descending so that row with `bar` is at the top and `baz` is at the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line:

```
data$item <- reorder(data$item,data$tot)
```

before `melt`ing.

The canonical StackOverflow question on this topic is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5208679/324364) and the answer is basically always "set the factor levels in the desired order", but how you do that in practice can vary from case to case in ways that are a little beyond the scope of a single StackOverflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `reorder()` within your `aes()` in `ggplot()`.

Something like this...

```r
    ggplot(
       data = data.molten,
       aes(x = variable, y = reorder(item, value), fill = value)  +
       geom_tile()+
       geom_text(aes(label = value))
```